# how to send GET parameters as JSON using any rest client

Tags: json, rest, parameters, get, request

I want to send a request with parameters as json. I tried to set these in request body but this doesn't work. Is there any other way to send parameters as JSON?

Thanks,

Comment: No I want to use a rest client to test rest somthing like Poster (firefox addon).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  data: JSON.stringify(myJsonObject),
  success: successCallback,
  dataType: 'json'
});
```